# The difference between "having seen"," having to see", and "having seeing", in the sentences down below?

Tags: grammar, writing, grammar-myths

The difference between "having seen"," having to see", and "having seeing", in the sentences down below ?

Following is an excerpt from ' A Study in Scarlet'.

1- "from a drop of water,"said the writer,"a logician could infer the possibility of an Atlantic or a Niagara without **having seen  or heard** of one or the other .

2- "from a drop of water,"said the writer,"a logician could infer the possibility of an Atlantic or a Niagara without **having to see or having to hear** of one or the other .

3- "from a drop of water,"said the writer,"a logician could infer the possibility of an Atlantic or a Niagara without **having seeing  or hearing**  of one or the other.

Could you also,please explain-***with examples***-why the rest are incorrect.

Comment: They can't all be excerpts from the book. You need to indicate which is the actual quote. Or if none is, and each is has changed something, you need to make that clear.

Answer (score 3):

The preposition *without* is followed by either a noun or a gerund (a verb + *ing* ending) that's why there is *hav**ing*** in all the sentences you've written.

> 1. without **having seen or heard** of one or the other .

Here you can see the [perfect gerund](https://www.grammaring.com/the-forms-of-the-gerund) that refers to a time before that of the verb in the main clause. That means:

> A logician **hadn't seen or heard** of neither the Atlantic or the
>   Niagara before but he could infer the possibility from a drop of water.

One more example of the perfect gerund:

> He denied **having been** married.

The perfect gerund *having been* refers to a time before *denied*: He denied that he **had been** married.

> 2. without **having to see or having to hear** of one or the other

In this sentence **having to** is a gerund form of the modal verb **have to** *do something* (= *need to do something*). That means:

> **There was no need** for a logician **to see or to hear** of neither the Atlantic or the Niagara to be able to infer the possibility from a
>   drop of water.

One more example of the gerund of *have to*:

> **Having to** wake up at 5 a.m. to be at work in time is very tiring.

That means you **have to** wake up at 5 a.m. not to be late at work and it's tiring.

> 3. without **having seeing or hearing** of one or the other.

Never head of using the gerund after the verb *have*. This sentence might be grammatically incorrect.

Comment: +1.  The preposition **without** "is followed by" ...